# Does Writer Monad guarantee right associative concatenation?

Tags: haskell, monads, writer

It was claimed in [Validations in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721609/validations-in-haskell) that use of a `Writer` guarantees right-associative concatenation.  However, this example seems to show otherwise.  What's the correct answer?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.String

data TM = TMempty
        | TMappend TM TM
        | TMfromString String

instance IsString TM where
  fromString = TMfromString

instance Monoid TM where
  mempty  = TMempty
  mappend = TMappend

instance Show TM where
  showsPrec d TMempty = showString "\"\""
  showsPrec d (TMfromString s) = showString $ show s
  showsPrec d (TMappend a b) = showParen (d > 0) $
    showsPrec 1 a .
    showString " ++ " .
    showsPrec 0 b

theWriter :: Writer TM ()
theWriter = do
  tell "Hello"
  replicateM_ 2 $ tell "World"
  tell "!"

main = print $ execWriter theWriter
```

Produces:

```
"Hello" ++ ("World" ++ "World" ++ "") ++ "!"
```

Comment: +1 for the simple example of using and implementing `showsPrec`.

Comment: Interestingly, if you replace `replicateM_` with `replicateM`, the output becomes `"Hello" ++ ("World" ++ ("World" ++ "" ++ "") ++ "") ++ "!"`

Comment: It's the difference between `sequence` and `sequence_`: `sequence = foldr (liftM2 (:)) (return [])` but `sequence_ = foldr (>>) (return ())`; the former generates more binds because it does things with the results.

Comment: In any case, `>>` is supposed to be associative.  But I am not a monadic lawyer.

Comment: @JoeyAdams: Indeed; if *w* follows the Monoid laws, `Writer w` will follow the Monad laws. But non-right-associative `mappend`s are usually inefficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed untrue. From the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html):

```
m >>= k  = WriterT $ do
    ~(a, w)  <- runWriterT m
    ~(b, w') <- runWriterT (k a)
    return (b, w `mappend` w')

...

-- | @'tell' w@ is an action that produces the output @w@.
tell :: (Monoid w, Monad m) => w -> WriterT w m ()
tell w = WriterT $ return ((), w)
```

So the chain of `mappend`s will mirror the chain of `(>>=)`s.

Answer (score 1):

`Writer [a]` doesn't guarantee right-associative concatenation, but you can get guaranteed right-associative concatenation with `Writer (Endo [a])`.